# XML Xpath Query

Tags: .net, xml, xpath

I have been converting some VB.Net XMl code to read specific XML by Elements as opposed to attribute values, and I have the following line that has stumped me:

```
Dim fNode As XmlNodeList = x.SelectNodes(String.Format("tables
                                                          /table
                                                            /field[
                                                              @pkid='{0}'
                                                            ]", fk))
```

My questions is regarding the end part, how do I write that to check an elements value as opposed to the specific attribute?  The specific element that I want to check is `<PK>` and I want to evaluate it against fk.

Thanks.

Comment: EDIT: The element that I want to check against fk is called PK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tables/table/field[PK='{0}']
```

There is nothing special about attributes in this context - you can test against the value of the `PK` element just as easily by simply removing the `@`.

Example input xml:

```
<tables>
    <table>
        <field>
            <PK>42</PK>
            <!-- Other fields -->
        </field>
    </table>
</tables>
```

Comment: Hi,  There are no elements in the newly defined XML that I am using.  The pkid value is now determined within a fully formed pk element.  It is that value that I would like to compare against fk.  Thanks.

Comment: Have it working now taking away the @sign like you said, but with the slight change to the code  "tables/table/field/pk['{0}']"  Thanks.